# Open an html file in new browser tab from cell (Markdown or python) in jupyterlab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to open an html file in a new browser tab in **Jupyterlab**. The jupyterLab that I'm working on is hosted in a container remotely.

The solution that I already tried are:

- **Using html tag**

  `'< a href="./docs/index.html" target="_blank"> Docs < / a>'`

This works fine with Jupyter, but when I run it on jupyterLab, I got the file get opened in jupyter tab (not browser tab)

- **Using webbrowser module**

```
import webbrowser, os
webbrowser.open('file:///' + os.path.realpath("docs/yenko/index.html"))
```

This solution also works fine in Jupyter notebook, but when I tried jupyterLab, I got false as output

- Using IFRAME

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame(src="docs/yenko/index.html", width='100%', height='1000px')
```

This solution works fine, but I kept it as alternative. Currently I'm looking to display the content in new browser tab, not inside the notebook.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In Jupyterlab an href to an external link like

`<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">test ext html</a>`

opens in a new tab of the browser, both in markdown and in a code cell with magic `%%html`

you can try creating a shared folder and writing the (usual) `href`s of your local `html` files with their full network path to see if jupyterlab doesn't interpret them as local

note:

normally, in jupyterlab, markdown cells render local links changing the actual href of, say, `test.html` into
`http://localhost:8888/files/test.html`

adding actually many more attributes to `<a>` on rendering, you can see this inspecting the jupyterlab's webpage (`ctrl+shift+i` in chrome)